# Created table from list not showing all elements

Tags: python, list, file, printing

I have a function that accept list as a parameter that was already created from another function. The list is printed in column row format. This function should assume that the first item in the list includes column titles and that the rest of the list includes values. The `showList()` function should be able to neatly display a list of 2 to 5 columns separated by spaces or tabs. in most cases it works fairly well but when it has more than one country to list it only lists one. Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
Country  Gold   Silver Bronze
(this space is actually a sequence of equal signs to represent a heading line)
United States 765    555    780
Great Britain 600  200      950
```

```
def showList(returned_List):
    header = '     '
    line = ''
    entries = ''
    for i in returned_List[0]:
        header += i + (' ')*5
    for k in range(len(header)):
        line += '='
    for j in returned_List[1]:
        entries += j +(' ')*5
    print(header, '\n', line, '\n', entries)
    return(returned_List)
```

Comment: You might be interested in [prettytable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is loop over the rows in `returned_list`, instead of hard-coding `returned_list[0]`:

```
def showList(returned_List):
    header = '     '
    line = ''
    entries = ''
    for row in returned_list:
        for i in row:
            header += i + (' ')*5
        for k in range(len(header)):
            line += '='
        for j in returned_List[1]:
            entries += j +(' ')*5
        print(header, '\n', line, '\n', entries)
        return(returned_List)
```

From your comments, I kinda see what you are looking for. Here's an adaptation of script I wrote a while back that'll help you:

```
def tabularize(inData, outfilepath):
    """ Return nothing
        Write into the file in outfilepath, the contents of inData, expressed in tabular form.
        The tabular form is similar to the way in which SQL tables are displayed.
    """

    widths = [max([len(row) for row in rows])+2 for rows in izip_longest(*inData, fillvalue="")]

    with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("+")
        for width in widths:
            outfile.write('-'*width + "+")
        outfile.write('\n')
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write("|")
            for col,width in izip_longest(line,widths, fillvalue=""):
                outfile.write("%s%s%s|" %(' '*((width-len(col))/2), col, ' '*((width+1-len(col))/2)))
            outfile.write('\n+')
            for width in widths:
                outfile.write('-'*width + "+")


outfile.write('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'starting'

    tabularize(infilepath, outfilepath, '...', False)

    print 'done'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Country     Code     Gold     Silver     Bronze     United States     USA     1063     853     737
      
 ====================================================================================================================================================================== 
 United States     USA     1063     853     737
     United States     USA     1063     853     737this was a bit problematic. This was the output:

Comment: @JacobHahn: The lack of formatting in comments is problematic, but I think I understand the problem. However, I'm unsure that I can fix very much without seeing the value of `returned_list` before this function is called

Comment: Here is an example of what returned list might look like. The first element in the list is always the header regardless of the amount of elements within the sublist                                                                 [['Code', 'Country'], ['TKM', 'Turkmenistan'], ['PAK', 'Pakistan'], ['KAZ', 'Kazakhstan'], ['CRC', 'Costa Rica'], ['AFG', 'Afghanistan'], ['TJK', 'Tajikistan'], ['UZB', 'Uzbekistan'], ['KGZ', 'Kyrgyzstan']]

Answer (score 0):

for i in returned_list[0]: only looks at the first entry.

you probably want:

for i in returned_list:

Comment: No. Each element in `returned_list` is a list itself. These sublists contain the columnar values that the OP wants to print out. So you'd want `for sublist in returned_list: for i in sublist:` See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17734197/198633)