# Arranging columns after rearranging indentation in Python

Tags: python

I have data set looks like:

```
atom 01 B   HEL A1001 -1.09 32.90 22.99  
atom 02 C   ARG A1002 -3.22 22.89 12.00  
atom 03 C1  ARG A1003 -2.99 18.32 22.13  
atom 04 CW2AARG A1004 -2.22 19.99 29.84  
atom 05 WS  HEL A1005 -3.22 18.33 14.21
```

...
What I'm looking for is to correct the 3rd lines indentation problem or to add a 'space' before AARG or to create a space column. It should finally look like..

```
atom 01 B    HEL A1001 -1.09 32.90 22.99  
atom 02 C    ARG A1002 -3.22 22.89 12.00  
atom 03 C1   ARG A1003 -2.99 18.32 22.13  
atom 04 CW2  AARG A1004 -2.22 19.99 29.84  
atom 05 WS   HEL A1005 -3.22 18.33 14.21
```

using `for line in map(str.split, inp): x=line[2]`
I was trying to select a column say by using `line[2]` i am getting a wrong column selection, because `CW2AARG` coming as single column entry not as `CW2` for `line[2]` and `AARG` for line `line[3]`.
Any ideas on how should I change my approach...

Comment: Can you show the code that isn't working (where you're "getting a wrong column selection"?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17734068/198633)

Comment: That isn't the same at all?  The current asker's problem is that a column has been joined with another, and he needs to split it properly.

Comment: yes! not same at all..

Comment: When this happens is it always the case that the amino acid ID is four letters long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that your amino acid ID will be four characters long when this column joining is happening, and that this is the only column with the problem, this code should work:

```
pdb_data = []
for line in open('input.txt'):
    line = line.split()
    if len(line)<8:
        pre = line[0:2]
        post = line[3:]
        col3 = line[2][:-4]
        col4 = line[2][-4:]
        new_line = pre+[col3,col4]+post
        pdb_data.append(new_line)
    else:
        pdb_data.append(line)
```

If it's not always four characters long you could try applying some basic rules for where to split the string:  if the characters in the string reach a number: split there.

Answer (score 1):

try slicing method to achieve what you want.
Do not think so complicated.
  Using `map(str.split,inp)`would make it only complex.